# Svelte each block rendering only the last item

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm trying to make a tag input component in svelte and I've encountered a strange `#each` block behavior. I have the following svelte code

```
<script>
  import Input from './Input.svelte'
  import Tag from './Tag.svelte'

  export let tagValues = []
  let currentTag = ''

  function handleEnter({ key }) {
    if (key === 'Enter' && currentTag) {
      if (tagValues.indexOf(currentTag) < 0) {
        tagValues = [...tagValues, currentTag]
      }
      currentTag = ''
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="relative">
  <Input bind:value={currentTag} on:keyup={handleEnter}></Input>
  {#each tagValues as t (t)}
    <Tag value={t}></Tag>
  {/each}
  {JSON.stringify(tagValues, null, 2)}
</div>
```

The idea is to get the input value when the user hits Enter key and add that value as a tag if it isn't present already. `Input` component behaves the same as `input` Html element. `Tag` component only has a `value` property which is text, this should render all the values of the `tagValues` array, but only shows the last one. I can confirm that the array includes correctly new tags, because I pasted a stringify version of it to HTML. This is how it looks with 1 tag

[image: One tag rendered]

And this is with two tags

[image: Two tags rendered]

How can I make this component to render all tags? I have tried to make my each block keyed but nothing changed.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Can you create codesandbox and send?

Comment: Check the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6768a4a9ffd04151938ea93149b13a1e?version=3.26.0) it works great.